# Website stops working nodejs

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have website on Ubuntu sever.

I have started process using this command

**sudo pm2 start app.js -i 0**

it was working fine.Today morning my client message me it's stop working. 
I have stoped the node and re-start the process again using same command.
Now I want to know the reason by this happens?

How i can do this to check the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Check your logs and figure out why it crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check pm2 logs folder ( PM2_PROCESS_USER_HOME_DIRECTORY/.pm2/logs)

May be server crash and you did't setup pm2 autostart

active pm2 autostart :

`pm2 startup ubuntu 
pm2 save`

Comment: Can you tell me where is pm2 logs folder . and  how to setup pm2 autostart